# Can committees see the list of all recipients when I send them my GRE score?

Tags: graduate-school, application, gre

When I send out my GRE record to universities, can they see the list of all recipients? I generated a PDF version of my GRE record by clicking the print button, it actually shows the recipient list. Can all the recipients see that? I think that information is supposed to be private.

Comment: I have called GRE and they say the score recipient list is for my reference only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, at least, the default seemed to be that the list of all recipients showed up on the form of the records sent to graduate programs. I know this because I was/am on admissions committees and saw such information. On another hand, I do also know that it is possible to suppress it, since in recent years most GRE reports seem *not* to show this to admissions committees.

Unfortunately, I do not know how the examinee arranges to suppress that information. It certainly is not done automatically, despite the obvious point that it should be private.

Comment: You can suppress the recipient information by editing the HTML file that you use to print GRE reports.